# does apex class api version impacts new features

Tags: apex, api, list, contains

If my apex class API version is 28, will there be any issue if i try to use List class contains method ?

I checked in debug logs, even if class has api version 28, i am able to use List contains method. Does api version anywhere else in my org override class api version making class api version meaningless ?

Comment: If you are stuck with api 28, you can make yourself a little utility class with API level 42 that can perform the `contains()` method for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Contains method`](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring18/release-notes/rn_apex_new_classes_methods.htm) was introduced recently; I guess in version `42.0`.

To use the it, you would have to upgrade API version of the class.

Note: Salesforce recommends to upgrade the API version after every 3 releases. But make sure to check if anything breaks after the upgrade.